# Facebook share button is not sharing correct title and description

Tags: facebook, addthis

I am trying to fix problem with FB share button
in
**http://davitpir.ack.neowebservices.co.uk/offer-61.html**

You can view the source (html code)
I have set the meta title, description etc correctly.

But when I click on share button it is sharing "Davit Pirvelashvili" which is the title of other pages not the offer page(i.e. the link I have mentioned above)

How can I make the FB share button share the correct title and description.

You can view-source of the above url to see the title/description that I have mentioned

**Update**

Strangly it is working fine for 
**http://davitpir.ack.neowebservices.co.uk/offer-83.html**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenGraph tags can get cached (I'm not sure the term FB uses). But if you test your URL with:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

It forces the cache to update.

*EDIT: After using the debug tool the title is correct for me.*